# a tag taking some extra space in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, space

I put an image inside the a tag. but when i gave border to the image and a tag. The A tag taking some extra space. it is not surrounding the image.how to overcome those extra space by 'a' tag. i am indicating a tag in red line.

My html:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://img165.imageshack.us/img165/1043/burnhr6.png"/></a>
```

Css:

```
img
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
a
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rEPXY/2/

Comment: The only HTML in your demo is: `<D src="http://img165.imageshack.us/img165/1043/burnhr6.png"/>`. I'm not sure what to make of that..

Comment: You can change this by making the <a> and <img> tags float left in your CSS, though I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for. see: http://jsfiddle.net/rEPXY/9/

Comment: but still you are getting some extra space below the image. why it is happening

Comment: I updated it to float the img too, it is fixed. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't see any extra space in Mike's answer.!?

Comment: [Possibly helpful.](http://www.welovecss.com/showthread.php?t=4132)

Comment: I think @RobHruska's linked page contains the answer, that "the text-descender" is to blame since the image is inline.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
a
{
    border:1px solid red; display:inline-block; line-height:0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how this image is going to be positioned on you website, you can fix this by floating the `<a>` and `<img>` tags. See revised jsfiddle for an example:

Html:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://img165.imageshack.us/img165/1043/burnhr6.png"/></a>
```

Css:

```
img {
    border:1px solid black;
    float: left;
}

a {
    border:1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

[www.jsfiddle.net/rEPXY/9](http://jsfiddle.net/rEPXY/9)

Comment: +1 good answer mike :) Added your solution into the post itself. (To make sure this post is standalone)

Comment: Thanks..It's working but it's affecting other element which i don't want to float left. But i can give some id or class for that. it's time consuming..Any way thanks for your code...

Answer (score 2):

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rEPXY/18/

Image is treated as inline, so its going to adhere to font-size and line heights, along with line breaks. Change the nature of the image and its container and you should be good. The CSS below for the `<a>` tag is using `inline-block` but you may also change it to `block` with a `width` property

If you float the `<a>` tag too, its going to become troublesome align it with other elements.

```
img
{
    border:1px solid black;float:left;
}
a
{
    border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[According to this](http://www.welovecss.com/showthread.php?t=4132), you can solve it by adding the following rule:

```
a img {vertical-align:bottom}
```

That seemed to work for me in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

What I dont understand is why you have a border on the a tag. I am guessing when you do add the border the a tag is interpreted by the browser as an element with content in it and thus it probably allocates the default line-height and adjusts the width to fit the content inside the tag.

Comment: i am not using border in my original code. i just used here to mention the extra space.